# Set a custom value (and fetch it) to every item (XTemplate) of a Ext.view.View

Tags: extjs

I would like to add a custom value to each item of a Ext.view.View, this is a window name that should be opened when the item will be clicked.

I'm reading the API docs and I found only how to set custom function, is a problem if I set a custom attribute too?

Thanks for any suggestion

What I'm reading: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.XTemplate

**Edit 1:**

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.desktop.Icons', {
  extend: 'Ext.view.View',
  alias : 'widget.iconsdataview',

  tpl: Ext.create('Ext.XTemplate',
    '<tpl for=".">',
    '<div class="mfo-view">',
    '<img src="{image}" alt="{image}" />',
    '<p>{title}</p>',
    '</div>',
    '</tpl>'
  ),

  itemSelector: 'div.mfo-view',
  store: 'Icons',
  style: 'margin: 2em;',
  overItemCls: 'mfo-view-over',
  trackOver: true
});
```

I would like to do something like this:

```
tpl: Ext.create('Ext.XTemplate',
        '<tpl for=".">',
        '<div class="mfo-view">',
        '<img src="{image}" alt="{image}" />',
        '<p>{title}</p>',
        '</div>',
        '</tpl>',
        mycustomproperty: '{property}'
      ),
```

and then on itemdblclick event (pseudocode)

```
itemdblclick(obj, ...) {
    openMyWindow(obj.mycustomproperty);
 }
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I don't really understand what you are asking. can you include some code (even pseudo code is helpful) to show what you want to accomplish?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like what I want is not possible because object created by template are htmlelement, and you have to do Ext.get to make them Elements, to actually use them as ExtJS objects.

I solved by accessing the store with the index of itemdblclick method.

**Edit 1:**

Even better, you can access the item with *record* parameter, without using index.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked to much in EXTJS 4.o mostly 3.3 but I believe you can do the following:

```
tpl: Ext.create('Ext.XTemplate',
        '<tpl for=".">',
        '<div class="mfo-view">',
        '<img src="{image}" alt="{image}" />',
        '<p>{title}</p>',
        '</div>',
        '</tpl>',
        { mycustomproperty: '{property}'
}
      ),
```

Comment: How to get in itemdblclick the item doubleclicked? I would like to fetch that property.

Comment: So you want to get have a doubleclick listener on something in the template?

Comment: Mh not exactly, I would like a custom property for each item that the template is applied to. Then in itemdblclick, triggered from a View, I would like to read this property.